# C# Can't debug Async method on API Controller

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method on the an ApiController that I am trying to debug. This method makes a call to an external API using SendAsync. Once I make this call, the debugging ends. I have had a similar problem in the past when using a console application. I was able to resolve it by using wait(). Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't believe that you want to do this in a web application.

```
        var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        var login = new LoginModel() { username = "test", password = "test" }; 

        msg.Content = new ObjectContent<LoginModel>(login, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), (MediaTypeHeaderValue)null);

        //Debugger exits after calling this line.
        var result = await WebApiApplication.HttpClientInstance.SendAsync(msg); 

        //Debugger never gets here. 
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        }
```

I am calling this method by browsing to it with a web browser. What do I need to do in order to debug this method in its entirety?

Comment: could you show the signature of controller action?

Comment: did you put the breakpoint at `if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)`? are their eny exceptions.

Comment: @Vinit - Good call. The SendAsync call was throwing an exception, however it was getting swallowed. Why is the exception hidden?

Comment: What do you mean "hidden"? Are you saying that the response to the client indicates everything was ok?

Comment: @DylanNicholson - I mean that I never saw the exception until I wrapped a try/catch around it. Normally the debugger breaks when it encounters an unhandled exception.

Comment: The answer is fine but you can also go to the debugger and trun on break on thrown exceptions.

Comment: @Dave I can only assume the debugger didn't consider it unhandled - depending on what frameworks etc. you're using that's not unusual (e.g. if you have ExceptionHandler middleware configured)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a try catch block to see what is going?

```
        var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        var login = new LoginModel() { username = "test", password = "test" }; 

        msg.Content = new ObjectContent<LoginModel>(login, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), (MediaTypeHeaderValue)null);

        try 
        {
            //Debugger exits after calling this line.
            var result = await WebApiApplication.HttpClientInstance.SendAsync(msg); 

             //Debugger never gets here. 
             if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
                var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do something with the ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: That won't compile, as you refer to `result` outside the scope it's declared in.

Comment: Made the correction thanks for catching that @DylanNicholson